# Sort on Multiple columns in QTableView

Tags: python, pyside2

I'm using Pyside2, Python 3.8

I have a QTableView, with a QSortFilterProxyModel Model. I managed to sort my rows on a single column. What I want to achieve is sort myTableView on the column 3 (contains String data), then on column 2 (contains Bool data) and then on Column 4 (contains integer data). See the below picture for an example
[image]

I've been trying about different why to do this, It seems that the hack my be in the lessThan() method, but It's very confusing to me.

Can someone give me a hint on how should I proceed?

Here's some samples of my code, If it helps any one.

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        ProxyModel = ProxyModel()
        TableModel = TableModel()
        ProxyModel.setSourceModel(TableModel)

        self.MyTableView.setModel(ProxyModel)

class ProxyModel(QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(ProxyModel, self).__init__()
        self._filter = "Aucun"

    def filterAcceptsRow(self, sourceRow, sourceParent):
        if self._filter == "Aucun": return True

        sourceModel = self.sourceModel()
        id = sourceModel.index(sourceRow, self.filterKeyColumn(), sourceParent)
        if sourceModel.data(id) == self._filter:
            return True
        return False

    def lessThan(self, left, right):
        print(left.row(), ' vs ',right.row())
        
        if left.column() == 3:
            leftData = int(self.sourceModel().data(left))
            rightData = int(self.sourceModel().data(right))
        if left.column() == 2:
            leftData = str(self.sourceModel().data(left))
            rightData = str(self.sourceModel().data(right))
        return leftData < rightData
        
class TableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):

    def __init__(self, mlist=None):
        super(TableModel, self).__init__()
        self._items = [] if mlist == None else mlist
        self._header = []
    
    def rowCount(self, parent = QtCore.QModelIndex):
        return len(self._items)

    def columnCount(self, parent = QtCore.QModelIndex):
        return len(self._header)

    def data(self, index, role = QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if not index.isValid():
           return None
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole or role == QtCore.Qt.EditRole:
            return self._items[index.row()][index.column()]
        return None
    
    def setData(self, index, value, role = QtCore.Qt.EditRole):
        if value is not None and role == QtCore.Qt.EditRole:
            self._items[index.row()-1][index.column()] = value
            self.dataChanged.emit(index, index)
            return True
        return False

    def addRow(self, rowObject):
        row = self.rowCount()
        self.beginInsertRows(QtCore.QModelIndex(), row, row)
        self._items.append(rowObject)
        self.endInsertRows()
        self.layoutChanged.emit()
```

Comment: what is the current problem with your code? and provide a [mre]

Comment: My code works, but for sorting on a single column, I want to implement sorting on multiple columns and can't figure out how to start

Comment: Your question is unclear, what do you mean by sorting multiple columns? could you show examples of the desired behavior

Comment: I've added an example in the post

Comment: Placing an image without a description does not help at all, so please: 1) Explain what you show in the image, what is the sorting criteria? and 2) provide an MRE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QSortFilterProxyModel` calls `lessThan` only once for each row pair with indexes set to `index(left_row, sort_column)` and `index(right_row, sort_column)`, so implementation must take this into account. Ignore column part and access columns you interested in.

```
def lessThan(self, left, right):
    row1 = left.row()
    row2 = right.row()
    model = left.model()
    for col in [3,2,4]:
        a = model.data(model.index(row1, col))
        b = model.data(model.index(row2, col))
        if a < b:
            return True
        elif a > b:
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: Thanks man ! It works perfectly fine !! Thanks for taking the time for understanding my question, and giving my this thoughtful answer.

Cheers